# Lack of EFI shell on machine

Tags: shell, operating-systems, efi

I don't appear to have an EFI shell on my machine, there's no option to access it through my BIOS and it never shew up in rEFInd when I used it. Is there any way I could install one?

Comment: For giving advice, we need to know the computer model and BIOS version.

Comment: For the model, that’s Stone Group (OEGStone) BOAMOT-481. Not sure about the BIOS version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EFI Shell is available as part of EDK II, the open-source UEFI core from Intel. You can download the pre-compiled `shellx64.efi` file from its GitHub – look for ShellBinPkg.zip under "Releases":

- [EFI Shell v2 binaries](https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/releases/download/edk2-stable202002/ShellBinPkg.zip) (official EDK2 build; for firmwares conforming to UEFI v2.3 or later)
- [Old EFI Shell v1 binaries](https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/tree/UDK2018/EdkShellBinPkg) (official EDK2 build)
- [Arch Linux wiki article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#UEFI_Shell)
- [Custom build script used by Arch Linux](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/PKGBUILD?h=uefi-shell-git)

Some firmwares offer a built-in option to launch the shell, expecting it to be named `\ShellX64.efi` and located in the root of the EFI system partition. If your firmware doesn't have such an option, then add a custom one via efibootmgr.

Comment: Is the EFI shell detection case sensitive?

Comment: No. Operations on FAT32 filesystem are not case-sensitive.

Comment: `EFI Shell v2 binaries` link is broken.

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub the link should work now